# Unable to install PaddleOCR on Python 3.11 with GitHub Actions on Windows OS

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, github-actions, python-3.11

I am trying to automate the installation of PaddleOCR using GitHub Actions for my project. The process works smoothly on other Python versions and operating systems.

However, I am encountering an issue specifically with Python 3.11 on the Windows operating system when running the GitHub Actions workflow to install the `PyMuPDF` library.

The error output is as follows:

https://github.com/eftalgezer/PlotScan/actions/runs/5731021239/job/15531033720

```
Building wheels for collected packages: fire, PyMuPDF, python-docx, future
  Building wheel for fire (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for fire (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for fire: filename=fire-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=116948 sha256=097baa9f9f54b25d733fb355444ab9944b21d927e9b868a0aec3856364492b8f
  Stored in directory: c:\users\runneradmin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\a7\ee\a5\19e91481be8bea594935d137578bfe77d6bf905e4595336f6b
  Building wheel for PyMuPDF (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for PyMuPDF (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for PyMuPDF (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [191 lines of output]
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: sys.argv: ['setup.py', 'bdist_wheel', '--dist-dir', 'C:\\Users\\runneradmin\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-wheel-7knel3hq\\.tmp-7bk_3mhd']
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: os.getcwd(): C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u26aisza\pymupdf_092cd445043d4d4ab040208f4c305ef7
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: __file__: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u26aisza\pymupdf_092cd445043d4d4ab040208f4c305ef7\setup.py
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: $PYTHON_ARCH: None
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: os.environ (155):
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ALLUSERSPROFILE: C:\ProgramData
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_HOME: C:\Android\android-sdk
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_NDK: C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_NDK_HOME: C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_NDK_LATEST_HOME: C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_NDK_ROOT: C:\Android\android-sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANDROID_SDK_ROOT: C:\Android\android-sdk
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     ANT_HOME: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\ant\tools\apache-ant-1.10.13
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     APPDATA: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Roaming
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR: C:\Program Files\Common Files\AzureCliExtensionDirectory
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     CABAL_DIR: C:\cabal
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     CHOCOLATEYINSTALL: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     CHROMEWEBDRIVER: C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\ChromeDriver
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     CI: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COBERTURA_HOME: C:\cobertura-2.1.1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COMMONPROGRAMFILES: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86): C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COMMONPROGRAMW6432: C:\Program Files\Common Files
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COMPUTERNAME: fv-az365-843
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     COMSPEC: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     CONDA: C:\Miniconda
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     DEPLOYMENT_BASEPATH: C:\actions
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP: 0
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     DOTNET_NOLOGO: 1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     DOTNET_SKIP_FIRST_TIME_EXPERIENCE: 1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     DRIVERDATA: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     EDGEWEBDRIVER: C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\EdgeDriver
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GCM_INTERACTIVE: Never
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GECKOWEBDRIVER: C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\GeckoDriver
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX: C:\
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GHCUP_MSYS2: C:\msys64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTION: __run
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTIONS: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTION_REF:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTOR: eftalgezer
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ACTOR_ID: 10411957
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_API_URL: https://api.github.com
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_BASE_REF:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_ENV: D:\a\_temp\_runner_file_commands\set_env_a51bbc0f-5c77-4a8b-a2c8-d73b77fff211
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_EVENT_NAME: push
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_EVENT_PATH: D:\a\_temp\_github_workflow\event.json
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL: https://api.github.com/graphql
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_HEAD_REF:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_JOB: build
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_OUTPUT: D:\a\_temp\_runner_file_commands\set_output_a51bbc0f-5c77-4a8b-a2c8-d73b77fff211
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_PATH: D:\a\_temp\_runner_file_commands\add_path_a51bbc0f-5c77-4a8b-a2c8-d73b77fff211
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REF: refs/heads/master
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REF_NAME: master
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED: false
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REF_TYPE: branch
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REPOSITORY: eftalgezer/PlotScan
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID: 664412195
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER: eftalgezer
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID: 10411957
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS: 90
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT: 1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_RUN_ID: 5731021239
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER: 258
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_SERVER_URL: https://github.com
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_SHA: 41c71cd0256e496d681cd08775572951f1a18703
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_STATE: D:\a\_temp\_runner_file_commands\save_state_a51bbc0f-5c77-4a8b-a2c8-d73b77fff211
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY: D:\a\_temp\_runner_file_commands\step_summary_a51bbc0f-5c77-4a8b-a2c8-d73b77fff211
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR: eftalgezer
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_WORKFLOW: Python app
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF: eftalgezer/PlotScan/.github/workflows/python-app.yml@refs/heads/master
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA: 41c71cd0256e496d681cd08775572951f1a18703
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GITHUB_WORKSPACE: D:\a\PlotScan\PlotScan
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GOROOT_1_18_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.18.10\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GOROOT_1_19_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.19.11\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GOROOT_1_20_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.20.6\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     GRADLE_HOME: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\gradle\tools\gradle-8.1.1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     HOMEDRIVE: C:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     HOMEPATH: \Users\runneradmin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     IEWEBDRIVER: C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\IEDriver
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     IMAGEOS: win22
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     IMAGEVERSION: 20230724.1.0
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     JAVA_HOME: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\8.0.382-5\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     JAVA_HOME_11_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\11.0.20-8\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     JAVA_HOME_17_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\17.0.8-7\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     JAVA_HOME_8_X64: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\8.0.382-5\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     LOCALAPPDATA: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     LOGONSERVER: \\fv-az365-843
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     M2: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.8.7\bin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     M2_REPO: C:\ProgramData\m2
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     MAVEN_OPTS: -Xms256m
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX: C:\npm\prefix
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: 2
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     OS: Windows_NT
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PATH: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\overlay\Scripts;C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\normal\Scripts;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7;C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64\Scripts;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\5.0\bin;C:\aliyun-cli;C:\vcpkg;C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\;C:\tools\zstd;C:\Program Files\Mercurial\;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\stack\2.11.1\x64;C:\cabal\bin;C:\\ghcup\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.1\bin\x64;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\GeckoDriver;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GitHub CLI;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx_bin;C:\npm\prefix;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\go\1.20.6\x64\bin;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64\Scripts;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.9.13\x64;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Ruby\3.0.6\x64\bin;C:\Program Files\OpenSSL\bin;C:\tools\kotlinc\bin;C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\8.0.382-5\x64\bin;C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q16-HDRI;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI2\wbin;C:\ProgramData\kind;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.16.101-hotspot\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\ProgramData\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\160\DTS\Binn\;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\pulumi\tools\Pulumi\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\maven\apache-maven-3.8.7\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Service Fabric\bin\Fabric\Fabric.Code;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Service Fabric\Tools\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\GitHub CLI\;c:\tools\php;C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\bin;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\ChromeDriver\;C:\SeleniumWebDrivers\EdgeDriver\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\SessionManagerPlugin\bin\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSSAMCLI\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin;C:\Users\runneradmin\.dotnet\tools;C:\Users\runneradmin\.cargo\bin;C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PATHEXT: .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PERFLOG_LOCATION_SETTING: RUNNER_PERFLOG
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PGBIN: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\bin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PGDATA: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14\data
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PGPASSWORD: root
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PGROOT: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\14
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PGUSER: postgres
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PHPROOT: c:\tools\php
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PIPX_BIN_DIR: C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx_bin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PIPX_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\pipx
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PKG_CONFIG_PATH: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64/lib/pkgconfig
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL: GitHub-Actions-win22
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK: Off
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: AMD64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: Intel64 Family 6 Model 85 Stepping 7, GenuineIntel
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROCESSOR_LEVEL: 6
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROCESSOR_REVISION: 5507
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROGRAMDATA: C:\ProgramData
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROGRAMFILES: C:\Program Files
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROGRAMFILES(X86): C:\Program Files (x86)
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PROGRAMW6432: C:\Program Files
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PSMODULEPATH: C:\Users\runneradmin\Documents\PowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\PowerShell\Modules;c:\program files\powershell\7\Modules;C:\\Modules\azurerm_2.1.0;C:\\Modules\azure_2.1.0;C:\Users\packer\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PUBLIC: C:\Users\Public
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHON2_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHON3_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHONLOCATION: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHON_ROOT_DIR: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RTOOLS43_HOME: C:\rtools43
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_ARCH: X64
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT: github-hosted
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_NAME: GitHub Actions 14
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_OS: Windows
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_PERFLOG: C:\actions\perflog
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_TEMP: D:\a\_temp
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_TRACKING_ID: github_fdbbe0e4-2a85-4027-9a4c-2501f0b34668
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     RUNNER_WORKSPACE: D:\a\PlotScan
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     SBT_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\sbt\
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     SELENIUM_JAR_PATH: C:\selenium\selenium-server.jar
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_EXT: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_EXTP: https://provjobdsettingscdn.blob.core.windows.net/settings/provjobdsettings-0.5.154/provjobd.data
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_NM: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_PFS: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_PT: 20
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_RDCL: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_TIS: mining
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_TRP: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_UE: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_V3PS: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     STATS_VMD: true
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     SYSTEMDRIVE: C:
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     SYSTEMROOT: C:\Windows
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     TEMP: C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     TMP: C:\Users\RUNNER~1\AppData\Local\Temp
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     USERDOMAIN: fv-az365-843
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: fv-az365-843
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     USERNAME: runneradmin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     USERPROFILE: C:\Users\runneradmin
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     VCPKG_INSTALLATION_ROOT: C:\vcpkg
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     WINDIR: C:\Windows
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     WIX: C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.11\
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PIP_BUILD_TRACKER: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-tracker-uqs6zbv6
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHONNOUSERSITE: 1
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PYTHONPATH: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\site
  PyMuPDF/setup.py:     PEP517_BUILD_BACKEND: setuptools.build_meta:__legacy__
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: mupdf_tgz already exists: C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u26aisza\pymupdf_092cd445043d4d4ab040208f4c305ef7\mupdf.tgz
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: Extracting C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-u26aisza\pymupdf_092cd445043d4d4ab040208f4c305ef7\mupdf.tgz
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: mupdf_local='mupdf-1.20.3-source/'
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: Building mupdf.
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: Cannot find devenv.com in default locations, using: 'devenv.com'
  PyMuPDF/setup.py: Building MuPDF by running: cd mupdf-1.20.3-source/&&"devenv.com" platform/win32/mupdf.sln /Build "ReleaseTesseract|x64" /Project mupdf
  '"devenv.com"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
  operable program or batch file.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
      main()
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 251, in build_wheel
      return _build_backend().build_wheel(wheel_directory, config_settings,
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 416, in build_wheel
      return self._build_with_temp_dir(['bdist_wheel'], '.whl',
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 401, in _build_with_temp_dir
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 488, in run_setup
      self).run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-jrkcwo01\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
    File "<string>", line 550, in <module>
    File "C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\Python\3.11.4\x64\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'cd mupdf-1.20.3-source/&&"devenv.com" platform/win32/mupdf.sln /Build "ReleaseTesseract|x64" /Project mupdf' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyMuPDF
  Building wheel for python-docx (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for python-docx (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for python-docx: filename=python_docx-0.8.11-py3-none-any.whl size=184518 sha256=26b59cd3d7f603ace7bf3198189f9571720fb133ea6aacd4e7eada6016a9792b
  Stored in directory: c:\users\runneradmin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\b2\11\b8\209e41af524253c9ba6c2a8b8ecec0f98ecbc28c732512803c
  Building wheel for future (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for future (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.3-py3-none-any.whl size=492053 sha256=731420c8b7ac491e519c603ee70c6bf80b8465a145e8ac3c361cf6d9b1240f6d
  Stored in directory: c:\users\runneradmin\appdata\local\pip\cache\wheels\da\19\ca\9d8c44cd311a955509d7e13da3f0bea42400c469ef825b580b
Successfully built fire python-docx future
Failed to build PyMuPDF
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyMuPDF, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by:

1. Downgrade the machine to Windows 2019 to use Visual Studio 2019.         `os: ["ubuntu-latest", "macos-latest", "windows-2019"]`. If you are trying to install it on your local machine this is not necessary
2. Set up Visual Studio 2019 on Windows

```
    - name: Set up Visual Studio 2019 for Windows
      if: matrix.os == 'windows-2019'
      uses: microsoft/setup-msbuild@v1.1
```

3. Install PyMuPDF by building the source code

```
    - name: Install PyMuPDF on Windows
      if: matrix.os == 'windows-2019'
      run: |
            [bool] $vsSetupExists = $null -ne (Get-Command Get-VSSetupInstance -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            if (!$vsSetupExists)
            {
              Write-Verbose "Installing the VSSetup module..."
              Install-Module VSSetup -Scope CurrentUser -Force
            }
            [string] $visualStudioInstallationPath = (Get-VSSetupInstance | Select-VSSetupInstance -Latest -Require Microsoft.Component.MSBuild).InstallationPath
            $env:PYMUPDF_SETUP_DEVENV = (Get-ChildItem $visualStudioInstallationPath -Recurse -Filter "DevEnv.exe" | Select-Object -First 1).FullName
            curl -OL https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF/archive/refs/tags/1.20.2.zip
            tar -xf 1.20.2.zip
            cd PyMuPDF-1.20.2
            python setup.py install
            cd ..
            rm -f 1.20.2.zip
            rd -r -fo PyMuPDF-1.20.2
```

The run code above `git clone ..` is to find the location of
devenv.com (devenv.exe). If you are trying to install on your local machine and know the path you can simply set `$env:PYMUPDF_SETUP_DEVENV = path/to/devenv.exe`. PyMuPDF 1.20.2 is the requirement of PaddleOCR.